# Mysql records with no child in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to get the messages that are childless within the same table

```
ID  parent_id  body
1   NULL       my first comment (parent)
2   1          my reaction on first comment (child)
3   NULL       comment without reactions
```

As you can see the message are related my the parent_id.
How can I get the parents without any child related. So me result would be

```
ID  parent_id  body
3   NULL       comment without reactions
```

I tried some stuff but I cant figure it out. Like select in select. On stackoverflow I could find some examples but does were mostly from 2 tables, not in the same. Maybe I mist does. Anyone can help me out?

Comment: But message 2 is also childless, why is it not in your results?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Message #2 is childless, but it has a parent (the first record).

Comment: So there are 2 condition to meet: childless and parentless.

Comment: Yhea that is correct @KIKOSoftware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a `NOT EXISTS` clause which asserts that a given record has no parents *and* has no children:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    t1.parent_id IS NULL AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.parent_id = t1.ID);
```

Comment: You could simply use `WHERE ISNULL(t1.parent_id)` to check that there's no parent.

Comment: I tried the one where you had 2 EXISTS functions, that triggerd without loading time. This however took more then a minute so I just cancelled it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: nvm, in the end i did not use 2 EXISTS, I use what @KIKOSoftware said, plus I got more records back.

Comment: SELECT *
     FROM msg t1
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM msg t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.parent_id)
      AND job_id IS NOT NULL
      AND parent_id IS NULL
     ORDER BY id DESC

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT parent_id 
    FROM table1
    WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
  )
```

Comment: Please check your query, it doesn't do what you think it does. It always helps if you format the query so you can easily read it.

Comment: Look at the description "I need to get the messages that are childless" he/she wants parent message without any child

Comment: I checked again, and I stand corrected, it does indeed do what it needs to do. Your subquery finds all parents, and then main query finds all messages that don't have a parent _and_ are not a parent. If you make the query better readable I'll upvote it, eventhough it would make a huge temporary table when there are a lot of messages (I'll be gone for an hour so upvoting can take a while, but I'll check back in when I'm back).

Comment: My query finds all parents, and then subquery finds parent_id of all messages that have a parent, so result exactly same as expected

Comment: check the result he/she expects